# How to prevent maven-assembly-plugin accessing remote repositories

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, nexus, maven-assembly-plugin

I have [the following problem](https://github.com/vorburger/opendaylight-simple/issues/37) with the maven-assembly-plugin:

In a build of a project [using this custom settings.xml](https://github.com/vorburger/opendaylight-simple/blob/master/.travis-maven-settings.xml) (which defines `<repository>` for https://nexus.opendaylight.org, for code and plugins, snapshot and releases), which makes everything else in the build than the maven-assembly-plugin fetch everything from this nexus.opendaylight.org, the maven-assembly-plugin spends an eternity querying trying (and failing) to fetch many `org.opendaylight` SNAPSHOT dependencies which are only available on `nexus.opendaylight.org` from other remote repositories, such as `oss.sonatype.org`, `repository.apache.org`, `nexus.codehaus.org`, `maven.glassfish.org` ... :-(

Presumably all these other Maven repositorites are listed in POM of some dependencies... but other Maven plugins ignore those - why doesn't maven-assembly-plugin, and how can it be made to?

You should be able to immediately reproduce this problem by doing:

```
git clone https://github.com/vorburger/opendaylight-simple/
cd opendaylight-simple
mvn -s .travis-maven-settings.xml clean package
```

It does not always happen, but should on first try; I think once it has tried Maven remembers it for 24h and then it happens again.

Comment: I have the same issue in my project. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @uldall nope. But reading my notes in https://github.com/vorburger/opendaylight-simple/blob/master/TODO.md it seems like I had partially worked around it using "-nsu -o" when I hit this. FYI I currently do not work on any projects using Maven, so I lost interest in this problem. Best of luck!

Comment: Created a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-951